# Can I ask questions about editing software?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video conversion question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/video-conversion-question)

I wish to ask a question about video editing software that I use for gaming videos. However, I realized that those type of questions may be irrelevant to this site as editing software has many other purposes than *just* editing gaming videos.

So, would that question be appropriate here? If not, what website would non-game-related software be posted?

Comment: [Hey, it's everybody's favorite question!](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/video-conversion-question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there's nothing gaming-specific about such a software, then no, I do not think it's appropriate here.

If you're looking for other sites on the Stack Exchange Network to ask these kinds of questions on, I guess the most appropriate is [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com).

Comment: A quick search on Area51 brings up [Audio-Video Production](http://avp.stackexchange.com/), which is in public beta. That seems like the best fit for such questions, and judging by the stats, it looks like they'll be happy to get some more traffic.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen: My only problem with audio/video production (and the main reason I haven't joined) is that, at least from the FAQ, it seems to be geared more towards professional A/V production.  Granted, their front page does show a lot of amateur (no offence) questions.  I would say SuperUser is a good fit, at least for now.

Comment: So what's stopping people from asking it on their Meta or to ask their mods on chat?

Comment: Thanks for not voting to close my question and rather answering it since it is *not* about video conversion, but video editing. :) I had searched "editing" and, "video editing" but that question had not come up.